# javascript compare two objects and print values

Tags: javascript

Compare Two javascript object and array and console respective values.can anyone help me please

```js
const Icons = {
  mail: 'fa fa-envelope',
  phone: 'fa fa-phone',
  user: 'fa fa-user',
  cart: 'fa fa-cart'
};

const icon = [
  'mail',
  'phone',
  'user',
  'cart'
];

icon.map(function(v, i) {
  console.log(i, Icons.v);
});
```

expected output:

```
0,fa fa-envelope
1,fa fa-phone
2,fa fa-user
3,fa fa-cart
```

getting undefined can anyone please tell me whats wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` as `Icons` doesn't have a property `v`.

Since `v` is a variable use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). i.e. `Icons[v]`

```js
const Icons = {
  mail: 'fa fa-envelope',
  phone: 'fa fa-phone',
  user: 'fa fa-user',
  cart: 'fa fa-cart'
};

const icon = [
  'mail',
  'phone',
  'user',
  'cart'
];

icon.map(function(v, i) {
  console.log(i, Icons[v]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Icons = {
 mail:'fa fa-envelope',
 phone:'fa fa-phone',
 user:'fa fa-user',
 cart:'fa fa-cart'
};

const icon = [
    'mail',
    'phone',
    'user',
    'cart'
];

icon.map(function(v,i){
  console.log(i,Icons[v]);  //try this
});
```